# PHP show error message on ajax submission

Tags: php, ajax, forms, validation

I am php beginner. I am submitting a form using ajax call. So after submission of the form user stay on the same page and do not go to reserve_seat.php since ajax call.

```
<form action="reserve_seat.php" method="POST">
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" value="Mickey">
<br>
Email:<br>
<input type="text" name="email" value="Mouse">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<script>
      $(function () {
        $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'reserve_seat.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Now after submission of the form I do some validation for email and if the email validation fail I want to show an error message above the form. May be insert a div showing that email not valid. How can I do that? My validation code below

```
    if( !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $insert = 'INSERT into reservation(name,email) VALUES ("'.$name.'", "'.$email.'")';
        mysql_query($insert);
         } else {
        //need help here to show error message 
}
    }
```

Comment: What does your ajax call to reserve_seat.php return based on success or failure? You'd need to return something there first, then inside your success callback you can perform an action(s), show div with error message, etc.

Comment: please use prepared statements, your command is suffering from sql injections: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection. That means someone could execute arbitrary commands in your sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<span id='error_message'></span>
```

In your ajax success:

```
success: function (res) {
    $('#error_message').text('');
    $('#error_message').text(res);
}
```

**PHP (reserve_seat.php)**

`echo` the error message, based on your requirement/condition.
In your case,

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $insert = 'INSERT into reservation(name,email) VALUES ("'.$name.'", "'.$email.'")';
    mysql_query($insert);
} else {
    echo "Invalid Email";
}
```

Comment: how can I echo the error message? html code is in index.php file

Comment: just try the way it is. in your current code, you are not taking response from ajax.

Answer (score 1):

$.ajax will get a response in its success method :

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'reserve_seat.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
          alert(data); // Alerts server response
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

You just need to actually send a response server side, you could simply echo a message with PHP :

```
if( !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email'])){
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];

  if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $insert = 'INSERT into reservation(name,email) VALUES ("'.$name.'", "'.$email.'")';
    mysql_query($insert);
  } else {
    echo "This message will be available in success method";
  }
}
```